# Custom Exception

Tags: apex, exception

I have started learning custom exception. I try to display only the exception message for my program.
my code:

```
 public class AccountContactHandler {
        public List<AccountContactWrapper> getAllAccounts_Contacts(){
            Integer count_of_Contact; Integer Count_Of_Account = 0;
                List<AccountContactWrapper> responseWrapper = new List<AccountContactWrapper>();
            Account[] accounts =  [Select id,Name FROM Account];
             try{ 
            for( Account accountSO : accounts){
               Count_Of_Account++;            
                 
                      if(Count_Of_Account>50)
                    {
                        throw new MyException('You can view only limited records.');                  }
                else if(Count_Of_Account<50)
                {
                
                     count_of_Contact =[SELECT COUNT() From Contact where Contact.AccountId = :accountSO.Id];
                responseWrapper.add(new AccountContactWrapper(accountSO,count_of_Contact)); 
                              }
                }  
                  }
                 catch(MyException e){
                 system.debug('Message : ' + e.getMessage());
                     System.debug('Limit is ' + Count_Of_Account);
                }
           
             return responseWrapper;
                 }
        public virtual class MyException extends Exception {}
}
```

how to display only the error message if limit exceeds and to display list if its within the limit.

Comment: where you wanna display? is it UI controller or justtrigger code?

Comment: Still I haven't learned UI controller. I tried to display in debug log.